# '_' is not convertible to StringLiteralConvertible error

Tags: ios, xcode, string, swift, dictionary

I'm having a problem declaring a dictionary in swift; my code is as follows:

```
var params = [
        "userComment":photo.userComment,
        "privacy":photo.privacy.value,
        "commentsPermission":photo.commentsPermission.value,
        "shouldHideExactLocation":photo.hideExactLocation,
        "tags":TagFormatConversionHelper.dictToArray(photo.hashtags)
    ] as [String: AnyObject]
```

The 'u' on the user comment string has the error "'_' is not convertible to StringLiteralConvertible" on it. I have used this same code further up in the class and it works fine.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Screenshot:

[image]

Class definition for photo:

```
@interface Photo : AWSPhoto

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger photoID;

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger userID;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *userName;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *uploaderFacebookId;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *uploaderGooglePlusId;

@property (nonatomic) NSArray *hashtags;
@property (nonatomic) NSDate *dateUploaded;
@property (nonatomic) double locationLatitude;
@property (nonatomic) double locationLongitude;

@property (nonatomic) NSString *userComment;
@property (nonatomic) Privacy privacy;
@property (nonatomic) CommentsPermission commentsPermission;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isTrending;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isVerifiedUser;
@property (nonatomic) PromotedStatus promotedStatus;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger upvotes;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger downvotes;
@property (nonatomic) Rating userRating;

@property (nonatomic) AssetType assetType;

@property (nonatomic) NSString *fileName;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *thumbnailFileName;

@property (nonatomic) GeoLocation *geolocation;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger locationID;

@property (nonatomic) BOOL userReported;

@property (nonatomic) BOOL hideExactLocation;


@property (nonatomic) BOOL isTopGroups;
@end
```

And TagFormatConversionHelper:

```
    struct TagFormatConversionHelper {

    static func arrayToDict(tagArray: [String], knownTrendingTags: [String]) -> [[String : AnyObject]] {

        var arr = [[String : AnyObject]]()

        for tag in tagArray {

            var dict = [String : AnyObject]()

            if contains(knownTrendingTags, tag) {

                dict["isTrending"] = 1

            } else {

                dict["isTrending"] = 0

            }

            dict["tag"] = tag

            arr.append(dict)
        }

        return arr
    }

    static func dictToArray(tagDictArr: [[String : AnyObject]]) -> [String] {

        var arr = [String]()

        for tagDict in tagDictArr {

            arr.append((tagDict["tag"] as! String))

        }

        return arr
    }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you posted. Perhaps you have a typographical error on an earlier line?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but unfortunately that is the first line in the method.

Comment: Well, you'll need to add more code and context for anyone here to help you. As the question's written, we won't be able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Consider removing some lines and seeing if it reproduces. Also you could update your question with info about what `TagFormatConversionHelper` and `photo` are and how they relate.

Comment: Please see the screenshot I have now included as well as the class definitions for the above.

Comment: Can't reproduce the error

Comment: Neither can I Zoff, as I said that same code works fine elsewhere in the class.

Comment: So ended up having to use the following workaround, ultimately it does the same thing but I still have no idea why it didn't work before.

        var params = [String : AnyObject]()
        
        params["userComment"] = photo.userComment
        params["privacy"] = photo.privacy.value
        params["commentsPermission"] = photo.commentsPermission.value
        params["shouldHideExactLocation"] = photo.hideExactLocation
        params["tags"] = TagFormatConversionHelper.dictToArray(photo.hashtags as! [[String : AnyObject]])